# Windows App Update removes shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-installer

I have an application with two versions:
- Version A - installs advertised shortcuts 
- Version B - installs non-advertised shortcuts

Both versions work from installation point of view separately, application shortcuts are correctly installed.
If I update from Version A to Version B, the desktop and start menu shortcuts are removed.

Did somebody faced the same problem?
What could be the reason?

UPDATE:
Using the ORCA tool, managed to view the properties table of MSI provided with **Version A** and it **does not have** the DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1 in Property table.
The **Version B does have** DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1.

If I remove the DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1 from Property table of the Version B msi installer file (using ORCA tool), upgrading from Version A to Version B does NOT remove the shortcut.

It seems, this difference causes the shortcut remove bug, but have no idea what could be the reason.

Comment: Are you doing a major or minor upgrade?

Comment: What do you mean by minor or major update?

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Log the upgrade (msiexec /I foo.msi /l*v upgrade.log)  and examine it or post it for our review.

Comment: Based on criterias from the link above, I do a major update.

Comment: Installer log link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w57ksmozccxoamn/upgrade_no_adv.log

Comment: I can't access dropbox at work.  Email to chrpai@iswix.com if you could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A review of your installation log indicates you are doing a major upgrade.  However your RemoveExistingProducts standard action is scheduled just before InstallFinalize.  This creates a race condition in that the uninstall of the previous version is happening after the installation of the new.  This is the most transitionally efficient technique but it assumes a bunch of component rules are not violated.

You need to schedule RemoveExistingProducts much earlier.  See:

[RemoveExistingProducts Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I can tell from the names of your components and custom actions that you are using a visual studio setup and deployment project.  That project was killed by Microsoft for suckiness and I don't think it supports changing where RemoveExistingProducts is scheduled. AFAIK there is only the "RemovePreviousVersions True|False) and not a setting for when to remove.

This probably requires  a postbuild hack of the MSI to fix.  One of the many reasons I don't use this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts are associated with components, so maybe you re-arranged the components or their guids and something broke. That's where I'd look. What exactly is different between the first setup and the upgrade regarding those components and their guids?

Comment: No component was added and no component suffered guid change between these version. The remarkable difference is the new entry in MSI file, in Property table, called DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS with value 1 (DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1)

Comment: This is probably some undocumented form of component rule violations.  A major upgrade with RemoveExistingProducts scheduled very early cures most strange problems like this.

Comment: If it is really a Visual Studio setup, it does not expose component Ids, so I assume you used Orca or some other tool to examine the guids? Another issue is that the VS major upgrade got badly broken between VS 2008 and 2010, so make sure you haven't got this issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2418919/en-us

Comment: PhilDW, thanks for the tip. Found out, that I also had a problem upgrading older versions of app (compiled with VS2008) to newer versions (compiled with VS2010). This installer compatibility is really annoying.